# How to get (extract) icon for iOS system app, like address book app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I want to sync my iPad app with AddressBook system app, so i want to use that icon in UI, which will enable sync process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use graphics which are copyrighted or trademarked to Apple, and your app will be rejected.  Instead, you'll have to create your own.

More information: http://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html